# How to Automate a password update on Oracle Databases for service accounts

Tags: python, oracle, automation, passwords

This is more of a concept question. I am on a monitoring team and we're currently starting to monitor Oracle Database. The company has a requirement to update passwords every 90 days. We need to monitor 1000s of Databases and do not want to have to go in to all of them and change the password every 90 days.

What is the best way to automate this process? I was thinking of trying to write a python script to connect to the database and then update the password; I know very little about oracle, is that even possible? is there a tool out there that would do something like this?

Looking for some preferred methods or recommendations on how to automate this process.

Thanks

Comment: Are these service accounts or user accounts? I can see putting in password policies that require users (humans) to change their passwords every 90 days but that seems like a lot for service accounts. You would need some way to update the applications that use the service accounts with the new passwords at the same time that you change the database passwords. Do you have DBA access on all the databases?

Comment: Yes I have Access and Yes they are service accounts. It is pretty tedious and it may turn out to be every 6 months or so if our request is approved but I will still need to go in and update password for 1000's of Databases and would like to run a script to look through it or something.

Comment: Are they Linux/Unix servers? Can you ssh into them as the unix user oracle? If so you could ssh into each one, connect to sqlplus / as sysdba and run alter user xyz identified by newpassword; on each one. If you have some central computer with access to all of them you can ssh from there.

Comment: Awesome Thanks I will look into that! I wanted to see what the best practices were for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is not clear to help in exploring a better solution

> Blockquote

I was thinking of trying to write a python script to connect to the database and then update the password

> Blockquote

This is valid, if you know the existing passwords (or have DBA access), then you can still do in a loop, given you're updating all to the same password, or have a a way to generate the password using a pre-defined pattern:
The command to change password:

```
alter user <username> identified by <password>
```

You can use python or any scripting language for the above in a loop once you can connect to user or sys

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can view what is going on about users accounts like so:

```
SELECT username, user_id, account_status, expiry_date
         FROM dba_users ;
```

e.g.

```
USERNAME      USER_ID      ACCOUNT_STATUS      LOCK_DATE      EXPIRY_DATE      CREATED
A      1      OPEN      [NULL]      12/28/03      09/29/03
B      2      OPEN      [NULL]      04/19/04      01/20/04
C      3      EXPIRED      [NULL]      06/22/04      06/26/01
```

You can ALTER a user as follows:

```
ALTER USER test VALID UNTIL 'Jan 31 2020';
```

Oracle will ask an EXPIRED user to reset his password on login via SLQ Developer or Toad for example.

Last make sure you set user profiles as needed:

```
select * FROM dba_profiles
```

e.g.

```
 select * FROM dbA_profiles where profile = ‘DEFAULT’;
PROFILE RESOURCE_NAME RESOURCE LIMIT
—————————— ——————————– ——– —————————————-
..
DEFAULT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME PASSWORD UNLIMITED
```

And finally to change a users profile:

```
alter user SCOTT profile APPLICATIONS;
```

Don't hesitate to ask me for more clarifciations.

Ted